# Exclude examples folder from npm (node_modules)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, libraries

I'm having some projects in Eclipse, and two of them are angular apps. I've downloaded and installed some libraries using `npm install`, but now in Eclipse, I've got a lot of validation errors coming from the `/examples` and `/test` folders. I know it's possible to exclude these folders from Eclipse validation, but since none of the project team members use the examples or tests anyway, I'd like to remove them. But npm install retrieves them again.

How can I exclude these folders from the libraries?

Comment: Actually you can't do this. Whatever is packed with the npm package is being delivered to your system :(